# How to reduce field on user profiles management using workflow in SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, office-365

I have some problem with my "holiday proposal" workflow in SharePoint Online (Office 365 - SharePoint 2010).
I have created field (integer) "Free days" in user profiles.

The main things is to reduce this "Free days" value after someone will create "holiday proposal" and when it will be accepted. "Free days" value will be reduced by the value of amount of days from the "holiday proposal".

This should check if the "holiday proposal" is greater than the number of of "Free days" and send email for this person. Or send email when the number of "Free days" will rise a 6 days left.

How would I do this using a Workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that is not possible as UserProfileManager is not accessible in SharePoint Online. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gajendra/archive/2012/03/15/workaround-for-userprofilemanager-in-sharepoint-online-o365-s.aspx).

Idea mentioned in the blog post above is probably not suitable for you as it's not probably syncing changes back to UserProfileDB.

Would creating a custom list for the "free days" work for you? You'd have columns "User" and "Free days", and modify that list from the workflow?